# CORS error in SocketIO via Express despite matching origin?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cors

## Solved: see Phil’s comment

### Solution: I was using a browser with weak error messaging, I switched browsers and found the issue in 5 seconds.

Original question, untouched for posterity:

The short version of this question is, why would CORS be failing if the origin matches the allowed origin (except for the path)?  See this error message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3030/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OhAxRtW. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:3030’).

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) makes clear that:

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins **(domain, scheme, or port)** other than its own from which a browser should permit loading resources.

In the error message I am receiving:

- both share the same scheme: `http`
- both share the same domain: `localhost`
- both share the same port: `3030`

If scheme, domain, and host all match, how is it possible to receive this error?

Direct comparison:

```
http://localhost:3030/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OhAxRtW
http://localhost:3030
```

Is it not true that path is not accounted for in CORS origin determination?  If so, how can this be a mismatch?

For clarification, here is my code:

```js
// server

import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  // @ts-expect-error
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3030"
  }
});

const port = 3030;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A user connected');
  
  // Handle socket events here
  socket.on('data', (payload) => {
    console.log(payload);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User disconnected');
  });
});

httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

```
// client

'use client';

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import io, { Socket } from 'socket.io-client';


export const SocketTest = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState<Socket | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const skt = io('ws://localhost:3030');
    setSocket(skt);
    skt.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to Socket.io');
    });

    // Handle socket events here

    return () => {
      skt.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Socket.io Demo</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (socket !== null) {
            console.log('socket emit');
            socket.emit("data", { message: "client data" });
          }
        }}
      >clicky</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SocketTest;
```

Note, if I change the `cors: { origin: ...` part to wildcard, everything works, but I don't wish to ship code with a wildcard for CORS.

```
  cors: {
    origin: "*"  // works
  }
```

Further troubleshooting per [Socket.io documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/) suggested I try validating via `curl`.  This worked as expected with no trouble, even while my CORS attempts were failing.  See below:

My `curl` command / result:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:3030/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"

0{"sid":"g4HqqSTX0oXDcEJpAAAJ","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":1000000}%
```

Comment: Try curl with `-verbose` flag

Comment: `curl` is not subject to the same-origin policy so you'll never really see any issues there

Comment: What browser are you using? Some have better error messages than others so if you can try a variety, you may be able to build a better picture. For debugging, use the dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the request and response headers. **Triple-check** the values in the request `Origin` and response `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: @Phil I was testing in Firefox (lesson learned).  I tested in Chrome and got much more detailed information to help me debug.  My client server was running on another port, so I switched the CORS options to match and this solved my problem.  Thank you for the browser tip, that was key.

Comment: I was kind of wondering why you even needed CORS support if client and server were on the same port 